# How to add categories in ScatterWithSmoothLines type chart into java aspose.slides api?

Tags: java, charts, scatter-plot, aspose, aspose-slides

HI I am trying to using first time aspose.slides for java api to create chart into pptx file. I need to some double values at Y Axis and some String value at X Axis. but i am able to doing this. because i am very confused to use this library. i have a lot study this library.

my code is -

```
    Presentation pres = new Presentation();

    ISlide slide = pres.getSlides().get_Item(0);

    //Creating the default chart
    IChart chart = slide.getShapes().addChart(ChartType.ScatterWithSmoothLines, 0, 0, 400, 400);

    //Getting the default chart data worksheet index
    int defaultWorksheetIndex = 0;

    //Getting the chart data worksheet
    IChartDataWorkbook fact = chart.getChartData().getChartDataWorkbook();

    //Delete demo series
    chart.getChartData().getSeries().clear();

    //Add new series
    chart.getChartData().getSeries().add(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 1, "Series 1"), chart.getType());
    chart.getChartData().getSeries().add(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 3, "Series 2"), chart.getType());

    //Adding new categories
    chart.getChartData().getCategories().add(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 0, "Caetegoty 1"));
    chart.getChartData().getCategories().add(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 0, "Caetegoty 2"));
    chart.getChartData().getCategories().add(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 0, "Caetegoty 3"));
    chart.getChartData().getCategories().add(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 4, 0, "Caetegoty 4"));
    chart.getChartData().getCategories().add(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 5, 0, "Caetegoty 5"));


    //Take first chart series
    IChartSeries series = chart.getChartData().getSeries().get_Item(0);

    //Add new point (1:3) there.
    series.getDataPoints().addDataPointForScatterSeries(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 1, 1), fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 2, 3));

    //Add new point (2:10)
    series.getDataPoints().addDataPointForScatterSeries(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 1, 2), fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 2, 10));

    //Edit the type of series
    series.setType (ChartType.ScatterWithStraightLinesAndMarkers);

    //Changing the chart series marker
    series.getMarker().setSize(10);
    series.getMarker().setSymbol(MarkerStyleType.Star);

    //Take second chart series
    series = chart.getChartData().getSeries().get_Item(1);

    //Add new point (5:2) there.
    series.getDataPoints().addDataPointForScatterSeries(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 3, 5), fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 4, 2));

    //Add new point (3:1)
    series.getDataPoints().addDataPointForScatterSeries(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 3, 3), fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 4, 1));

    //Add new point (2:2)
    series.getDataPoints().addDataPointForScatterSeries(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 4, 3, 2), fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 4, 4, 2));

    //Add new point (5:1)
    series.getDataPoints().addDataPointForScatterSeries(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 5, 3, 5), fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 5, 4, 1));

    //Changing the chart series marker
    series.getMarker().setSize(10);
    series.getMarker().setSymbol(MarkerStyleType.Circle);



    pres.save("/home/echasro/Desktop/TODAY/AsposeScatterChart.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx);
```

I am creating this slide like -like =https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFfIQ.jpg

but i need to add categories like = 12/12/2014,12/13/2014,14/12/2014 etc at X Axis.

I need this type chart on pptx file -[Link of required format file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B802gaEQepAwd3l3RzFjSnZPaTg/view)

Please suggest me any idea do this complete.
Thank for reading

Comment: please give me suggestion someone

Comment: Similar question posted at http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/601120/how-to-add-categories-in-scatterwithsmoothlines-type-chart-into-java-aspose.slides-api.aspx too.